# Human resources in (easy)redmine and automatic representation of their holidays in Gantt

Tags: redmine

Can I do the following in (easy)redmine and what plugins would I need?

Step 1: Create Human resources and set holidays for them

Step 2: Create tasks with a start and duration and assign them to resources

Step 3: Connect the different tasks

Expected result: When I move a task to a duration that has a resource holiday in it the task should be adjusted in length

I actually can't work out how to do this. I don't know if I am special but I think this would be the basic functionality for a project planning tool. Why would I use a software at all if I need to check holidays by hand for all dependendant tasks when moving/changing one of the earlier ones?

Comment: I suppose you want to extend estimation time + delivery date. You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

What you described is **"Leave management plugins"**. They are used to manage leave days of employee - employee can apply for leave days, managers can approve.

> I checked out some leave management plugin, such as
>   http://www.redmine.org/plugins/leave_management_system, but it seems
>   that it does not support your "automatically extend length" function.

I think there are many reasons not do build the function:

1. I suppose when you talked about task length, you were talking about ***estimation length***. Because actual time is logged independently. If the estimation length is automatically extended, it will **distorts** the numbers. In short sprint (2-week for example), one 16-hour task can become 40-hour task if the assignee leave for 3 days.
2. **In Scrum this function is not actually helpful**. You need to adapt to change frequently, which means you need to always know your position. And knowing your position means you need to remember who is doing which, which one will leave on which days, which tasks currently on this sprint and who should be in charge of the task if original assignee is absent.
3. People often leave unplanned. For example if they are sick, they can't plan it. In case of holiday, they plan it early and give it to you early. You should put it to calendar, and ***the best way to deal with this situation is not to "extend task length", but to figure out who is the substitute to handle what needs to be done.***